# Capture screenshot of web page in safari app extension

Tags: safari, safari-app-extension

I am converting legacy Safari extension to Safari app extension, Here's [a link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/converting_a_legacy_safari_extension_to_a_safari_app_extension/)

My legacy extension used safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.visibleContentsAsDataURL function to capture screenshot of active tab, how can I do that with Safari app extension? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to get the screenshot of the web page

1) send a message from the injected script to the app extension using safari.extension.disptachMessage

2) Below method in SafariExtensionHandler class will be invoked.

```
func messageReceived(withName messageName: String, from page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : Any]?)
```

3) screenshot can be taken using "page" parameter in the above mentioned function.

```
page.getScreenshotOfVisibleArea { (NSImage)

}
```

NSImage is the screenshot of the web page

Remember you can only get screenshot of currently visible area of the web page not the whole page.